# Provide external Bean before context start

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a Java API for a service and I want to extract it to a library.
I am using **spring 4.3.3**

Right now there is a bean called `ApiConfig` which is simple pojo.

```
public class ApiConfig {
   private String host;
   private String username;
   private String password;
}
```

and the values are read from a properties file.

I would like to be able to construct and provide this class **before** the context starts (several components have this class as `@Autowired` dependency).

For instance:

```
public class LoginService {

    @Autowired
    private ApiConfig apiConfig

    [...]
}
```

Basically, I would like to do something like this:

```
public static MyApi get(ApiConfig apiConfig) {

     //Here I want to provide this apiConfig as singleton bean that would be used everywhere
    provide somehow this class as bean
    // here all beans are loaded and the it fails because it cannot resolve ApiConfig
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ContextConfig.class);
    MyApi myApi= context.getBean(MyApi.class);
    return myApi;
}
```

The method MyApi.get(AppConfig) would be used by other java applications by adding dependency in `pom.xml`

Is there a way I can do this? Providing the ApiConfig bean and then initialize all the application?

Basically to let Spring know that there is also this bean, before starting context with `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ContextConfig.class)`

**UPDATE**

The idea would be this, in any application using this library.

```
public static void main(String asdas[]) {
    ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig();
    config.setUsername("BOBTHEUSER");
    //config.set etc
    MyApi api = MyApi.get(config);
    api.doOperation();
```

Comment: Why? Just make it a regular spring bean and just inject the values. You don't need to initialize it outside the scope of the application context.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

Actually `@Autowire` is enough. Make the ApiConfig a Bean and autowire it where it's is necessary. Spring resolves the proper order.

If you have two beans and one need the second to be initialized before creation use `@DependsOn` annotation

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig  {
    @Autowired
    private ApiConfig apiConfig

    @Bean(name="apiConfig")
    public ApiConfig apiConfig(){
        ... init the config ...
        return apiConfigInstance;
    }

    @Bean(name="myApi")
    @DependsOn("apiConfig")
    public MyApi myApi(){
        MyApi api = new MyApi(apiConfig);
        return api;
    }
}
```

Code from [the example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_dependson_spring) modified

Comment: I can't hardcode values in a configuration file. Those values are provided by an external source

Comment: I did not even mention a configuration file. I mean configuration class where you can add any desired logic - reading from file, from DB, from external source etc.

Comment: I meant `@Configuration` class, I updated my question. Do you have any example that fits to the expected usage?

Comment: I honestly don't understand how this could work in my case

Comment: Then add the code to your project, add logs/breakpoints and run it